# Calling parent constructor Java

Tags: java, constructor

So I am attempting to make a java GUI calculator and started to wonder if there would ever be a difference in the scenario where one class extends another one, to call super.functionname instead of just functionname in the extended class.

```
class frame extends JFrame{
       public buttonframe(){

        // any difference between this.add.. or super.add..

       }
}
```

I then made a couple of classes to experiment a little and I came over something I don't quite understand.

```
class A{
   public A(){
       System.out.println("A"); 
       h();
   }

   public void h(){    
       String className = this.getClass().getName();
       System.out.println(className); 
   }
}

class B extends A{
   public B(){   
       System.out.println("B");
       h(); 
   }   
}
```

Running:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   new A(); 
   new B(); 
}
```

Produces the output:

```
> A calculator.A 
> A calculator.B
> B calculator.B
```

I know that the extended class will call the constructor of the parent class, but why does it produce the result calculator.B (though I don't know why it has to do this, but I assume `A classname = new B();` has something to do with it) in the second output line, instead of calculator.A when it is the constructor called from the Class A?

EDIT:

```
class A{
public A(){
  //Can I instantiate a new B() and somehow ouput "A"?
 //I can do it using A.hs(); but can I do it: 

 //Using the method h() but with a specific keyword infront of h() so 
 //that it always refers to the method h() of the class A. 
 h(); 
}
public static void hs(){
 System.out.println("A"); 
}
    public void h(){
    System.out.println("A"); 
    }
}

class B extends A{
   public B(){
       h(); 
}
   public void h(){
    System.out.println("B"); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is because of the statement :

```
String className = this.getClass().getName();
```

The current object(`this`) when called as `new B()` is B and hence the class name of `B`.

---

So, the complete sequence as in your case would be :

```
A() => prints A => call h()  with current object of 'A' => prints classname of A

B() => calls super c'tor A()  => prints A => call h() with object of 'B' 
    => prints classname of B => prints B => call h() => prints classname of B
```

Comment: That does make sense when I think about. I realize that I haven't been"extending classes enough" lately as every time I use the this keyword it is within the same class only, and so I have started to associate the this keyword with the class instead of the object itself.

Comment: There is one thing I am wonder about though. A classname = new B(), where the function h() is ran in the A constructor, and both have the function h(), where the class A prints A and the class B prints B.  Is there a keyword that refers to A.h() used in the constructor of A? so that new B() will output A. I can't use this, and I can't use super in A(). I realize I can use a static function but is that the only thing I can do? I am very new to Java, but have some experience in Csharp.

Comment: Quite not clear to me, what you just asked. Would still try, in case you need to refer to the instance of either A or B you would need to create one or use static references from the class.

Comment: I added in some code to help you visualize what I meant.